# Dump MySQL database with Qt

Tags: mysql, qt4, dump, into-outfile

I have this slot:

```
void Managment::dbExportTriggered()
 {
    save = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, trUtf8("Export db"),
                              QDir::currentPath() + "Backup/",
                              trUtf8("Dumped database (*.sql)"));

    sqlQuery = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '" + save + ".sql' FROM Users, Data";
    //QMessageBox::critical(0, trUtf8("query dump"), QString::number(query.exec(sqlQuery)));
    query.exec(sqlQuery);
 }
```

And I have this query:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE " + save + " FROM Users, Data";
```

I execute normally but no dumped file appear, the `backup` directory has the right permission, the dumped database must be in client.

**UPDATE:**
After a search I found that the `INTO OUTFILE` query will dump database in the server not in the client as I was thought, so my question now how can I dump database in remote MySQL server, any quick methods with out any external tools like `mysqldump` client.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: Another approach is to call [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) with [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html). With some google-fu [this](http://mysql-gui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/qt-mysql-gui/backup.cpp) seems to be an example:

```
..
if (allDatabases->isChecked()) {
    arguments << "--all-databases";
  } else {
    arguments << "--databases";
    foreach(QListWidgetItem *item, databasesList->selectedItems())
      arguments << item->text();
  }
  proc->setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
  QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
  proc->start("mysqldump", arguments);
..
```

Thus, you can also add some parameters to dump only a **specific table**.

**Edit:**

Just note from the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) on the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement:

> If you want to create the resulting
>   file on some **other host** than the
>   server host, you normally **cannot use**
>   SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is
>   no way to write a path to the file
>   relative to the server host's file
>   system.

Thus you must roll your own, or you can use `mysql -e` as suggested by the above documentation.

Comment: I don't wont to use mysqldump, because my be MySQL bin directory not present in PATH variable environment of the system.

Comment: Well, one option is to package the mySQL client in your app if you are on windows. You can also have a setting in your app that points to the binaries. If you are on unix your mysql binary is normally in the path and mysqldump is part of the mysql-client package which you'll need anyway.

Comment: it may be that he has licensing issues if he distributes the mysql binaries with his application if his application isn't open source.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` creates a file on the MySQL server machine, with permissions matching whoever the MySQL server runs as. Unless you have root access on the MySQL server to retrieve the file that you're exporting, `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` is unlikely to do what you want.

In fact, I think I'd go so far as to say that if you're trying to use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` from a GUI client, you're probably taking the wrong approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you dump/print save to check it's valid? Does currentPath() return a trailung "/"?
2. Could there be difference between the path as seen by your client program and as (to be) seen by the server?
3. Does the user have the necessary privileges (file privilege for sure, maybe more)
4. Can't you get an error message from the log?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors running the sql statement?

I notice that you're concatenating the filename into the SQL query without surrounding it by quotation marks. Your code will yield something like

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE /path/to/somewhere FROM Users, Data
```

but the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) says it wants something like

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/somewhere' FROM Users, Data
```

Also keep the following in mind:

> The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. `file_name` cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as `/etc/passwd` and database tables from being destroyed.

If you're looking on your client, you won't see the file there, even if the operation succeeds.

Comment: I update my slot to be so:
`void Managment::dbExportTriggered()
 {
     save = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, trUtf8("Export database"),
                              QDir::currentPath() + "Backup/",
                              trUtf8("Dumped database (*.sql)"));

     sqlQuery = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '" + save + ".sql' FROM Users, Data";
    // QMessageBox::critical(0, trUtf8("export test"), QString::number(query.exec(sqlQuery)));
    query.exec(sqlQuery);
 }`
The returned path apear like this:
`SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/usr/home/SIFE/Desktop/Management-dev/fdf.sql' FROM Users, Data`

Comment: @Ken no, the documentation said that the dump will be in the server if the directive set, in my condition, the directive is not present, I tried the some query in MySQL CLI and I get this: `ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/usr/home/SIFE/Desktop/Management-dev/fdf.sql' (Errcode: 13)`.

Comment: @SIFE: What directive is not present? The only place a MySQL `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement can write is onto the server. There's *no way* for it to write into the client (unless the client and server happen to be the same machine). `Errcode: 13` is an `ERRNO` of 13, which means permission denied. This is probably because the `mysql` user (in `/etc/passwd` -- the permissions the MySQL server runs with) doesn't have permission to write to your home directory.  I think the rule is this: In general, `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` doesn't do what you want in a client/server setting.

Comment: @Ken this `directive secure_file_priv`.

Comment: @SIFE: The dump will be on the server no matter what. `secure_file_priv` just adds security by requiring that the the outfile be in a particular directory.

Comment: @Ken Yes, I know that, unfortunately I figure it late.